# Generating An Amortization Schedule

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, amortization

I have been tasked with creating a program that will generate an amortization schedule. I have only done a bit of research so far, but I need to calculate out payments, interest per payment and principal per payment. Can any one point me in the right direction to figure this out? While I will be writing this in RPG, I am sure others could make use of this algorithm in the future.

(Update) Okay, so how do I calculate based on a 365 day year?

Comment: If the app is important, in my opinion you should ask an accountant this question, and use the same formulae that an accountant would use. Even a "correct" answer, which is fine for an unimportant app, might produce results which fail to follow accounting practices/regulations for your jurisdiction.

Comment: Yes, but they use a vendor program to calculate out the payments. I need to duplicate this in my code. Of course, I can't just see how they calculated the payments...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up creating. I have posted the whole test program. It is written in RPG, but should be easily be figured out for any other languages.

```
 H ActGrp(*caller) BndDir('MODULES') DftActGrp(*no)
   //*********************************************************************
   // Program . . . . . AMORT
   //*********************************************************************
   // Printer/Display Files
 FAMORTDF   CF   E             WORKSTN sfile(SFL01:rrn01)
   //*********************************************************************
   // Named Constants
  /copy modules/qcopysrc,statuscopy

   // Named Indicators
 D indicatorPtr    S               *   Inz(%Addr(*IN))
 D                 DS                  Based(IndicatorPtr)
  /copy modules/qcopysrc,scrncopy

   // Subfile  Fields
 D rrn01           S              4P 0 inz(0)

   //*********************************************************************
   // Misc Fields
 D* Monthly Payment
 D m               S             12P 2        
 D* Principal
 D p               S             12P 2                                      
 D* Interest
 D i               S              5P 3                                      
 D* Length (in Years)
 D l               S              3P 0                                      
 D* Monthly Interest
 D j               S             10P10                                      
 D* # of Months
 D n               S              5P 0                                      
 D* Current Monthly Int.
 D h               S             12P 2                                      
 D* Current Principal
 D c               S             12P 2                                      
 D* New Balance
 D q               S             12P 2                                      

   //*********************************************************************
   // External Program Procedures

   // Internal Subprocedures
 D Init            PR
 D Main            PR
 D SubfileFilled   PR              N
 D ClearScreen     PR
 D IsValidData     PR              N
 D LoanPayment     PR            12P 2
 D  principal                    12P 2
 D  interest                      5P 3
 D  loanPeriod                    3P 0
 D  paymentsYear                  3P 0

   // External Subprocedures
   ///copy modules/qsrvsrc,p.string

   //*********************************************************************
   // Entry Parms
 D AMORT           PR                  extpgm('AMORT')
 D AMORT           PI
   //*********************************************************************
  /free
   Init();
   Main();

   *inlr = *on;
  /end-free

 P*--------------------------------------------------
 P* Procedure name: Init
 P* Purpose:
 P* Returns:
 P*--------------------------------------------------
 P Init            B
 D Init            PI

  /free

   pgm = 'AMORT';
   sflDsp = *off;

   return;

  /end-free
 P Init            E


 P*--------------------------------------------------
 P* Procedure name: Main
 P* Purpose:
 P* Returns:
 P*--------------------------------------------------
 P Main            B
 D Main            PI

  /free

   dow (not F3) and (not F12);

     write OVR01;
     exfmt CTL01;
     ClearScreen();

     if (IsValidData()) and (not F3) and (not F12);

       // Fill the header information
       dPayment = LoanPayment(dLoanAmt:dIntRate:dLoanPrd:dPayYear);
       dNumPaymnt = dLoanPrd * dPayYear;
       m = dPayment + dExtraPay;
       p = dLoanAmt;
       q = p;

       // Fill the table
       if (SubfileFilled());
         sflDsp = *on;
       endif;
     endif;

   enddo;

   return;

  /end-free
 P Main            E


 P*--------------------------------------------------
 P* Procedure name: SubfileFilled
 P* Purpose: Fill the subfile
 P* Returns:
 P*--------------------------------------------------
 P SubfileFilled   B
 D SubfileFilled   PI              N

 D isFilled        S               N
 D x               S              4P 0
 D intCume         S             12P 2
 D extraPayCume    S             12P 2
 D payDate         S               D
 D payment         S             12P 2
 D extraPayment    S             12P 2

  /free

   isFilled = *on;

   sflClear = *on;
   write CTL01;
   sflClear = *off;
   rrn01 = 0;
   x = 0;

   // Setup the work fields
   payment = dPayment;
   extraPayment = dExtraPay;
   payDate = dStartDate;

   // Create records until there is a zero balance
   dow (q > 0);

     x += 1;
     eval(h) h = p * j; // Monthly Interest

     // Adjust for final payment
     if (p < m);
       m = p + h;
       payment = p;
       extraPayment = h;
     endif;

     // Calulate Principal
     c = m - h;
     // Calulate the new balance
     q = p - c;

     // Accumulate the interest and extra payments
     intCume += h;
     extraPayCume += extraPayment;

     // Determine the next pay date
     select;
       when dTerms = '1'; //Yearly
         payDate += %years(1);
       when dTerms = '2'; //Semi-Annual
         payDate += %months(6);
       when dTerms = '3'; //Quarterly
         payDate += %months(3);
       when dTerms = '4'; //Monthly
         payDate += %months(1);
       when dTerms = '5'; //Bi-Weekly
         payDate += %days(14);
     endsl;

     // Fill the subfile
     sPayNum = x;
     sPayDate = payDate;
     sBegBal = p;
     sSchedPay = payment;
     sExtraPay = extraPayment;
     sTotPay = m;
     sInterest = h;
     sPrincipal = c;
     sEndBal = q;
     sCumeInt = intCume;

     // Move the End balance to the beginning balance
     p = q;

     rrn01 += 1;
     write SFL01;

   enddo;

   // Return the calculated information to the header
   dActPaymnt = x;
   dTotInt = intCume;
   dTotEPay = extraPayCume;

   if (rrn01 < 1);
     isFilled = *off;
   endif;

   return isFilled;

  /end-free
 P SubfileFilled   E


 P*--------------------------------------------------
 P* Procedure name: ClearScreen
 P* Purpose:
 P* Returns:
 P*--------------------------------------------------
 P ClearScreen     B
 D ClearScreen     PI

  /free

   c = 0;
   h = 0;
   i = 0;
   j = 0;
   l = 0;
   m = 0;
   n = 0;
   p = 0;
   q = 0;
   dPayment = 0;
   dNumPaymnt = 0;
   dActPaymnt = 0;
   dTotEPay = 0;
   dTotInt = 0;

   return;

  /end-free
 P ClearScreen     E


 P*--------------------------------------------------
 P* Procedure name: IsValidData
 P* Purpose: Validate the data on the screen
 P* Returns: True or False
 P*--------------------------------------------------
 P IsValidData     B
 D IsValidData     PI              N

 D isValid         S               N

  /free

   if (dLoanAmt <> 0) and (dIntRate <> 0) and (dLoanPrd <> 0) and
      (dPayYear <> 0) and (dStartDate <> %date('0001-01-01'));
     isValid = *on;
   else;
     isValid = *off;
   endif;

   return isValid;

  /end-free
 P IsValidData     E


 P*--------------------------------------------------
 P* Procedure name: LoanPayment
 P* Purpose: Calculates the payment
 P* Returns:
 P*--------------------------------------------------
 P LoanPayment     B
 D LoanPayment     PI            12P 2
 D  principal                    12P 2
 D  interest                      5P 3
 D  loanPeriod                    3P 0
 D  paymentsYear                  3P 0

 D retMonthlyPayment...
 D                 S             12P 2

  /free

   eval(h) n = loanPeriod * paymentsYear;
   eval(h) j = interest / (paymentsYear * 100);

   eval(h) m = principal * (j / (1 - (1 + j) ** -n));

   return m;

  /end-free
 P LoanPayment     E
```

This code has been tested against our loan calculator. If test vs. Excel, it was off about 32 cents on a $200,000 loan. I am sure that is do to rounding issues.

Answer (score 8):

When I was buying my first home recently, I wrote a JavaScript app for my personal use.

Here's a modified snippet of my code to determine the monthly payment:

```
var balance = 200000; // for example
var periods = 360; // 30 years
var monthlyRate = (0.065)/12;  // 0.065= APR of 6.5% as decimal
var monthyPayment = (monthlyRate /(1-(Math.pow((1+monthlyRate),-(periods)))))*balance;

for (var i=0; i<360; i++) {
  var interestForMonth = balance * monthlyRate;
  var principalForMonth = monthlyPayment - interestForMonth;
  balance -= monthlyPayment; // probably should be -= principalForMonth see comments below
  // output as necessary.
}
```

Pretty easy to make an amortization table after that. (As others have mentioned, do watch out for rounding errors, I didn't adequately deal with this issue in my implementation.)

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of sites that offer these formulas.  One is below:
http://www.math4finance.com/financial-formulas.php

No fancy algorithms are needed, as the formulas are generally quite simple.

Comment: I don't necessarily need code. I just a better direction than what Wikipedia gives. I need to be able to create a DB record set for all of the payments.

Answer (score 2):

Formula for Amortization Schedule in C#

```
            numerator = i * principle * (Math.Pow(1 + i, n));
            denominator = (Math.Pow(1 + i, n) - 1);

            /* Calculation of Amortization Payment Amount  */
            payment = numerator / denominator;
```

Answer (score 0):

Brian is right. The formulas are quite simple.

If you want your solution to be a good one, you'll pay attention to roundoff error.  If you just let roundoff error accumulate and propagate you can off by several cents at the end of the schedule.  With careful programming, you'll minimize the error.

Also, if you have MS Excel on your computer,  you can download an amortization template from MS office online.

Answer (score 0):

```
var annuity =  P * (i + i / (Math.pow(1+i,n) -1));

//P: principal, I: periodic interest rate, N: number of periods
```